# Determine if splitting two TextFrames will split a paragraph in InDesign

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

`TextFrame#nextTextFrame` tells me if a TextFrame overflows; I can also split the two TextFrames the way *StorySplitter* does.

What I can't seem to figure out is: does the second TextFrame start with a new paragraph, or does a single paragraph extend between the two?

I need this in order to reconstruct the flow afterwards, externally: I need to know if I have to merge the last paragraph of the first TextFrame and the first paragraph of the second TextFrame, or if instead they are two distinct paragraphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They *would* be considered the same `Paragraph` object. You can test this yourself with something similar to the following code (assuming there is a paragraph that spans two text frames and the text frames are linked together).

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;

var frame1 = doc.pages[0].textFrames[0];
var frame2 = frame1.nextTextFrame;

var para1 = frame1.paragraphs.lastItem();
var para2 = frame2.paragraphs.firstItem();

alert(para1 === para2);
```

Comment: Right on. "Paragraphs" are part of a running *story*, and you can only have a single story in a list of linked text frames. The story may even end "out" of the last frame (then it's overset). But no manipulation of its *containers* will physically break up a paragraph -- it's one of the backbones of how InDesign works with text.